# When I try to increment score value to set it in a TextView my app crashes

Tags: java, android, int

I want to set `score.setText(points)`. `score` is a `TextView`

In my game, `if` the user guess the word correct, I want to get `word.length`, then take the `.length`, add it to `int points`, post the `score` then generate another word.

How can I do this in a very simple way?

Here is code that crashes

```
if (word.length() > 10) {
    points + 10;
    score.setText(points);
}
```

If this is a duplicate please link me to the post.

Comment: Under which circumstances does it crash? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Your trivia about what you're doing is quite unrelated to your problem. That's fine, but at least the title should be descriptive.

Comment: @Mike Milla I have answered and changed the title of your question since doesn't match your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setText` receives a char sequence, 
try this

```
if (word.length() > 10) {
    points +=10;
    score.setText(points+"");
}
```

Comment: `Integer.toString(points)`, no..? That's how you'd usually do it

Comment: `"" + points` is simpler and concise. The point is that if it's an `int`, then Android thinks it's a resource ID.

Comment: @Droidman That works too, but there are multiple ways of converting an `int` to a `String`. What is in the answer and what you stated are only two examples.

Comment: @Droidman is not necessary write 'Integer.toString(points)', as Zhuinden and Jashaszun have said is a more coincise and simpler form

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually incrementing points - you need to do `points += 10`, along with what Silverstorm said.